# How to make a folder in Apache directory accessible over LAN

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to have only some folders of Apache/www directory accessible over LAN in a windows environment. We can do that by changing the conf file, but alll folders get the read permissions.

Any suggestions.

-A

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that you mean file level access, rather than access through a web browser, why not simply create a regular folder share? You can then set the combination of share and file/folder level permissions to suit your needs.